# How can I detect which Garbage Collector is in use?

Tags: c#, mono

I would like to detect which Garbage Collector is running at runtime in my mono service. Is this possible?

Comment: Why is this important? How does knowing alter your coding?

Comment: It allows me to understand GC behavior and access certain features that might not be in one GC at runtime (this is mostly true of .Net Runtime GC's).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
public static bool IsRunningWithSGen ()
{
    return System.GC.MaxGeneration > 0;
}
```

and the alternative for Boehm:

```
public static bool IsRunningWithBoehm ()
{
    return System.GC.MaxGeneration == 0;
}
```